# Property 'minRows' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & StandardTextFieldProps' in materialUI textField component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<TextField
        id='standard-multiline-flexible'
        multiline
        // maxRows={2}
        rows={1}
        minRows={2}

        size='small'
        value={value?.comment}
        variant='standard'
        onChange={(e) => setValue({ value: value?.value, comment: e.target.value })}
      />
    </div>
```

//Property 'minRows' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & StandardTextFieldProps' in materialUI textField component.

Answer (score 0):

Although somehow understandable, your question shoulde be written in a clearer way, with some describing text and with more details about your development set-up.

Apart that, you cannot use the `minRows` (or `maxRows`) props when the `rows` prop is set.